# How to take multiple screenshots of videos automatically?

Tags: video, screenshot, screen-capture

I have a batch of 20 thirty-minutes videos and need to have screenshot of 10 seconds interval. How can I make batch screenshots of videos without the need to watch the videos? Is there any tool, or software to make batch screenshot of videos?

Thanks,